# How to copy entire vector into deque using inbuilt function? (in C++)

Tags: c++, vector, stl, deque

I want to know that is there any inbuilt function to do this task

```
vector<int> v;
deque<int> d;
for(auto it:v){
    d.push_back(it);
}
```

I just know this way to copy the values of a vector in deque and I want to know is there any inbuilt function to perform this task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Pepijn Kramer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16649550/pepijn-kramer) said in the comments [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74238912/how-to-copy-entire-vector-into-deque-using-inbuilt-function-in-c#comment131070339_74238912) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74238912/how-to-copy-entire-vector-into-deque-using-inbuilt-function-in-c#comment131070429_74238912), you can use the overload (2) for the [assign](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/assign) member function that takes a range

```
d.assign(v.begin(),v.end());
```

or use the iterator-range [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/deque), overload (5)

```
std::deque<int> d{v.begin(),v.end()};
```

Or in C++23, you can do

```
auto d = std::ranges::to<std::deque>(v);
```